# Field of real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ is an ordered field.

Tags: real-analysis, logic

I am reading a real analysis book. In that book it is stated that the set $\mathbb{R}$ of real numbers contains a subset $\mathbb{R}^{+},$ called the set of all positive real numbers, satisfying properties:

$0 1.$  Given any $a\in\mathbb{R},$ exactly one of the following statements is true: 
$$a\in\mathbb{R}^{+}; a=0;-a\in\mathbb{R}^{+}.$$

$02.$ If $a,b\in\mathbb{R}^{+},$ then $a+b,ab\in\mathbb{R}^{+}.$

And by using these properties we define order relation in $\mathbb{R}.$ But my question is what about proof of existence  of such a subset $\mathbb{R}^{+}$ of $\mathbb{R}?$ Are these axiom? i.e. ordered axiom. I don't know exact meaning of Axiom. I only know that Axiom means that they are self maid, these are assumption, or there some proof of existence of such a subset of $\mathbb{R}?$ Please suggest me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: How is $\mathbb{R}$ defined in the book you are reading? Is the existence of $\mathbb{R}^+$ part of the definition?

Comment: Firstly defined $\mathbb{N},$ then $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ then it is assumed that there is a set $\mathbb{R}$ containing $\mathbb{Q}$ satisfying algebraic properties and then come to what i said....

Comment: How does the book define $\mathbb R$? Without a def'n we cannot prove anything about it..... It is always good to check the def'ns because a lot of basic properties of things  are obtained directly from the def'ns.

Comment: You can prove that the set of all squares of real numbers has the properties required of ${\bf R}^+$.

Comment: if possible give suitable proof in answer column...thanks..

Comment: @GerryMyerson Can we prove ordered Axioms in actually??

Comment: I stand by what I wrote: you can prove that the set of all squares of real numbers has the properties required of ${\bf R}^+$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: You've an extra $0$. And can you prove the properties without the completeness axiom?

Comment: What's a zero here or there among friends?

Comment: Which Real Analysis book you are reading?

Comment: A Course in Calculus and Real Analysis by Sudhir Ghorpade

Comment: You are quoting part of section 1.1 of the book by Ghorpade and Limaye. Have a look at first few paragraphs of that section which explain that the section is identifying assumptions about the real numbers to be used in the rest of the book. Yes, these are "axioms", but why do you single out the ordering properties for your question? [To other commenters: Amazon's "look inside" feature will show you the relevant parts of the book.]

Comment: @GerryMyerson: See the last section of my updated answer for why it is circular to define $\mathbb{R}^+$ as the set of squares of non-zero reals and then define ordering in terms of $\mathbb{R}^+$. =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$
\def\qq{\mathbb{Q}}
\def\nn{\mathbb{N}}
\def\zz{\mathbb{Z}}
\def\rr{\mathbb{R}}
$If your book defines $\rr$ with algebraic properties and order properties, with additive identity $0$, then we can simply define $\rr^+ = \{ x : x \in \rr \land x>0\}$. Then you can proceed to prove the properties that you have mentioned. The existence of $\rr^+$ is given by an axiom that allows you to construct the set I've given as its definition. You don't need to worry about that now, but it's called the axiom of set specification.

If your book does not define $\rr$ with order properties, and instead defines $\rr$ to have a subset $\rr^+$ with those properties you stated, then it's simply axioms as you guessed. Of course it is a good question as to whether there is even such a structure as $\rr$ with a subset $\rr^+$ with all the claimed properties. There are two main ways one can construct it from $\nn$.

### Cauchy sequences

The first way is by Cauchy sequences of $\qq$, where $\qq$ is constructed from $\nn$ by any way you like. $\qq$ is easily ordered, and in particular it is trivial to tell whether an element is positive, negative or zero. We can define for any two Cauchy sequences $f,g$ from $\qq$ that $f \equiv g$ iff for every $d \in \qq^+$ there is some $k \in \nn$ such that $|f(n)-g(n)| < d$ for every $n \in \nn_{\ge k}$. We can now construct the equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences modulo $\equiv$. Let $o$ be the constant $0$ sequence and $i$ be the constant $1$ sequence. Define addition and multiplication on Cauchy sequences pointwise and show that they respect $\equiv$, namely that if $a \equiv b$ and $c \equiv d$ then $a+c \equiv b+d$ and $a \times c \equiv b \times d$. Also define $f < g$ iff there is a $k \in \nn$ and $r \in \qq$ such that $f(n) + r \le g(n)$ for every $n \in \nn_{\ge k}$. We then can prove **trichotomy**, namely that exactly one of $f \equiv g$ or $f < g$ or $g < f$ hold. This is useful in proving the existence of multiplicative inverse, since if $f \not\equiv o$ then $f < o$ or $f > o$, and hence $f$ is eventually nonzero, so we can define a sequence $g$ that is eventually pointwise the multiplicative inverse of $f$, which would give $f \times g \equiv i$.

Note that in this construction the ordering is already there, so identifying $\rr^+$ is trivial. It is clearly pointless to construct $\rr$ in this way without defining the ordering along the way.

### Dedekind cuts

The second way is by Dedekind cuts. In this case it might be easiest to construct in the sequence $\nn \to \qq_{\ge 0} \to \rr_{\ge 0} \to \rr$. It is of course possible to go via $\nn \to \zz \to \qq \to \rr$ but proving all of the arithmetic properties of Dedekind cuts of $\qq$ involves of a whole lot of cases, whereas if we go from $\qq_{\ge 0}$ to $\rr_{\ge 0}$ the cases get shifted to the last step where it is purely algebraic manipulation.

In this approach we might choose to construct $\rr$ without defining the ordering, and note that the construction of $\rr$ from $\rr_{\ge 0}$ is via constructing $\rr^+ = \rr_{\ge 0} \smallsetminus \{0\}$ and then $\rr^-$ as a separate copy of $\rr^+$ (considered to have a negative sign attached to each element) and then $\rr = \rr^+ \cup \{0\} \cup \rr^-$ and defining the operations according to the sign. This would trivially satisfy the two properties you stated, and it is justifiable to finally define ordering based on the sign.

### Comparison

The technical details of the construction of $\rr$ by Dedekind cuts are much more hairy than that by Cauchy sequences, and it is not quite justified from the intuitive understanding of real numbers as magnitudes that can be approximated to arbitrary precision. But both yield essentially the same result, since there is exactly one Dedekind-complete ordered field up to isomorphism.

However, both approaches extend in different ways. Cauchy sequences can be used to construct the completion of any [metric space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space), regardless of whether the metric space is a total order. Dedekind cuts can be used to construct the completion of any [total order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order), even if it is not a metric space.

### $\rr^+$ as the set of non-zero squares?

This section is for those who are interested in why $\mathbb{R}^+$ with the properties specified in the question must be axiomatized and cannot be constructed using the field axioms alone (as I said in my first paragraph constructing it is trivial if you already have ordering).

Someone suggested that $\rr^+$ is the set of all squares of non-zero reals. That is true but can only be proven **after** having essentially defined ordering on $\rr$, in which case it is circular to define $\rr^+$ as suggested. To state this precisely; the sentence "$\forall x \in \rr\ \exists y \in \rr\ ( x = y^2 \lor x = -y^2 )$" (where "$y^2$" denotes "$y \times y$") cannot be proven using the field axioms for $\rr$. This is trivial to see, by observing that $\qq$ satisfies the field axioms but $\neg \exists y \in \qq\ ( 2 = y^2 \lor 2 = -y^2 )$.

Better still, even if you add axioms saying that every odd-degree polynomial over $\rr$ has a root in $\rr$ (as in the third axiomatization of a real closed field on [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_closed_field#Definitions)), it is insufficient, and the reason is that [adjoining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_extension#Definitions) all those roots to $\qq$ results in a field in which every element is in some odd-degree finite field extension of $\qq$, by the [tower law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_field_extension#The_multiplicativity_formula_for_degrees), and so $\sqrt{2}$ will never be in the resulting field, again by the tower law.

Comment: I don't think $\mathbb{R}$ is defined (in the book OP is talking about) with order properties. It is explicitly mentioned in the post that, "And by using these properties we define order relation in $\mathbb{R}$."

Comment: @user170039: Well then too bad if the book doesn't even bother to give the definitions it's using. I believe it's not possible to define and prove the ordering properties without some use of the completeness axiom.

Comment: To define order properties, I don't think it is necessary to use completeness axiom. For example, we may say for all $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ we will write $a<b$ if there exists $c\in \mathbb{R}^+$ such that $b=a+c$ (where $\mathbb{R}^+$ is the set satisfying the properties OP listed).

Comment: @user170039: Yes that's if you already have $\rr^+$. It's impossible to define $\rr^+$ using only algebraic properties of $\rr$. One needs something like the axioms for real closed fields.

Comment: @user170039: I've edited my post to give a brief answer to the possible question of how to prove the existence of such structures with the stated properties.